# how to display "0" when I use group by in sql query

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have table in database(sqlite).The table has two columns:

```
samochod_id  samochod_data_dodania    
1            2012-11-13
2            2012-12-18
3            2012-12-21
4            2013-01-03
5            2013-02-16
6            2013-02-27
7            2013-04-03
```

**I am using query:**

```
 select     strftime('%Y',samochod_data_dodania) as year,
            strftime('%m',samochod_data_dodania) as month,            
            count() ile 
 from samochod 
 where samochod_data_dodania between '2012-09-11' and '2013-05-26'
 group by year,month
```

**result:**

```
year   month  ile
2012   11     1
2012   12     2
2013   01     1
2013   02     2
2013   04     1
```

**I'd like:**

```
year   month  ile
2012   09     0
2012   10     0
2012   11     1
2012   12     2
2013   01     1
2013   02     2
2013   03     0
2013   04     1
2013   05     0
```

how to do it ? please help:)

Answer (score 1):

You want to move the conditions into the aggregation and out of the `where` clause:

```
 select strftime('%Y',samochod_data_dodania) as year,
        strftime('%m',samochod_data_dodania) as month,            
        sum(case when samochod_data_dodania between '2012-09-11' and '2013-05-26' then 1 else 0
            end) as ile 
 from samochod 
 group by year, month;
```

This assumes that you have at least one record for each month.  If not, then you need a left outer join:

```
select year, month, count(*) as ile
from (select '2012' as year, '09' as month union all
      select '2012', '10' union all
      select '2012', '11' union all
      select '2012', '12' union all
      select '2013', '01' union all
      select '2013', '02' union all
      select '2013', '03' union all
      select '2013', '04' union all
      select '2013', '05'
     ) ym left outer join
     samochod
     on ym.year = strftime('%Y', samochod_data_dodania) and 
        ym.month = strftime('%m', samochod_data_dodania) 
group by ym.year, ym.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in your case but you can test below method:

1. after insert data in table you can sort there column with below clause.

ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2.

i hope it will help.